# Trying to filter elements in a vector, but keep on getting error

Tags: search, binary-tree

I'm trying to filter a string of 2 vectors based on what they have. By that I mean my vector vector1 contains `["01","11","10"]` and another vector **vector2** which was created recursively using `options()` function to make binary numbers based on the digit=2 `["00","01","11","10"]`. I want to sort through both of them  and the value which is in vector2 but not in vector1 to another string of vectors. So using the above example I want a 3rd vector to contain `["00"]` which should be a string.

This is my code but on the last for loop where I actually do the filtering it gives me an error

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> options(int width)
{
    if (width == 1)
    {
        return {"0", "1"};
    }
    std::vector<std::string> rest = get_combs(width-1);
    std::vector<std::string> appended;
    for (const auto& s: rest)
    {
        appended.push_back(s + '0');
        appended.push_back(s + '1');
    }
    return appended;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> vector1 {"01", "11", "10"};
    std::vector<std::string> vector2 = get_combs(2);
  
    for (int i = 0; i < vector2.size(); i++){
        if ( vector2[i] in  vector1 ){  <-- error
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

The error says

```
no viable conversion from
      '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
      std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >,
      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
      std::allocator<char> > >::value_type' (aka
      'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
      std::allocator<char> >') to 'bool'
    if( vector2[i] in  vector1 ){
        ^~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/basic_string.h:816:7: note: 
      candidate function
      operator __sv_type() const noexcept
      ^
```

I'm not sure what to do, can somebody help me?

Comment: C++ is not Python, we don't have `in` keyword.

Comment: `in` ? Did you confuse c++ with python? One can play some tricks to make `xbar[i] in fvalues` work, but without such tricks `in` has no meaning in c++

Comment: [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) or [`std::any_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)?

Comment: For your question, it looks like `get_combs` is working, which means it should be removed. Please see how to make a [mcve]. Also, if your vectors are sorted, you can use `set_difference` to solve this problem without a loop.

Comment: You should be doing something like this do find out the values in a vector:

   

    if (std::find(fvalues.begin(), fvalues.end(), xbarl[i]) != fvalues.end())
    {
         // your code
    }

Comment: please do not vandalize your question. Questions are not only for you to get an answer, but also for future readers. Even when closed as duplicate the question can serve as entry point for others with similar question

Answer (score 1):

C++ has no `in` operator. The compiler doesn't recognize it, but it also doesn't know it's there, so it gives some other random error.

```
bool contains =false;
for (auto item : fvalues) {
 if (item == xbarl[i]) {
  contains = true
}
}
 if(contaisn){
   ...
```

Comment: fvalues.contains(...), make sure you are using c++20

Comment: @BigBasherSucks Why can you not use the algorithm module?

Comment: @BigBasherSucks The `std::vector` member function `contains` does not require `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: @BigBasherSucks for (auot item : vector) if item ==myItem

Comment: Edited the answrr